# Adding numbers from a list of integer to listbox

Tags: regex, vb.net, listbox

I am currently having issues with trying to get a list of integers to show in a listbox.
I have more numbers to show, however i cant even get one number to show.
There is no error, the listbox but shows this `System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.Int32]`

```
 Dim URL = New Uri("http://www.hurriyet.com.tr/sans-oyunlari/sans-topu-sonuclari/")
    Dim WebClient As New HttpClient
    Dim Source = Await WebClient.GetStringAsync(URL)

    Dim ListofNumber As List(Of Integer)
    ListofNumber = New List(Of Integer)

    Dim WebCode1 As String = "<span id=""_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblresutone"" class=""hurriyet2010_so_sanstopu_no_text"">([^>]*)</span></div>"
    For Each item As Match In (New Regex(WebCode1)).Matches(Source)
        ListofNumber.Add(item.Groups(1).Value)
    Next
    listBox1.Items.Add(ListofNumber)
```

Comment: You can extract data from HTML easily with HtmlAgilityPack - why regex? Also, the issue is that you `Add` rather than `AddRange` with `listBox1.Items.Add(ListofNumber)` (or  you can replace `ListofNumber.Add(item.Groups(1).Value)` with `listBox1.Items.Add(item.Groups(1).Value)`)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I prefer Regex, I want to add the number to a list because there are going to be 6 other numbers that i will scrap. I want them in a line, not in a row

Comment: @Werdna try `item.Value`... Also this `listBox1.Items.Add(ListofNumber)` ***should be*** `listBox1.Items.AddRange(ListofNumber)`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you're adding a single item to the list, which is the `List(Of Integer)` object.  You need to add each item in the list separately, like this:

```
For Each i As Integer In ListOfNumber
    listBox1.Items.Add(i)
Next
```

Or, more simply:

```
listBox1.Items.AddRange(ListOfNumber)
```

As was already mentioned in the comments, but bears repeating, regex is typically the wrong tool for the job when you're parsing HTML.  Using an HTML parser/DOM would be preferable in most cases.

Comment: G'day Steven, i dont have the option to "AddRange" is this because its a windows 8 app?

Comment: Well, since you haven't specified which UI framework you're using and which version of the .NET framework you are using, it's hard to say.  In any case, if there is no `AddRange` method, then the `For` loop option should still work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
listBox1.Items.Add(ListofNumber)
```

...it should be:

```
listBox1.DataSource = ListofNumber
```

This way you are binding your list of objects (in your case `ListofNumber`) to the `listBox`.

In fact you can bind any type of list, and the result shown in the `listBox` will be the `.ToString()` of each one of the items (in your case: `int.ToString()`, which is the string of the number).

An alternative to bind the data source would be: `listBox1.Items.Clear()`, and then add your items one by one through `listBox1.Items.Add(yourItem)`, or as a group with `listBox1.Items.AddRange(ListofNumber)`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is with the ID on WebCode1 as ID's are meant to be used once and that is the case in the source downloaded.

Please try this

[image]

```
Dim URL = New Uri("http://www.hurriyet.com.tr/sans-oyunlari/sans-topu-sonuclari/")
Dim WebClient As New HttpClient
Dim Source = Await WebClient.GetStringAsync(URL)
Dim WebCode1 As String = "class=""hurriyet2010_so_sanstopu_no_text"">([^>]*)</span></div>"
ListBox1.DataSource =
    (
        From T In (New Regex(WebCode1)).Matches(Source) _
        .Cast(Of System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match)() _
        Select T.Groups(1).Value) _
    .ToList
```